# Laravel - multiple routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm doing a simple project. I want it to be as minimal as possible so I tried to create system where I can create pages and they're placed at `localhost/{page?}`

But, here's the problem. I also want some routes to be defined (e.g. route `/blog`) like below.

```
Route::get('/{page?}', ['as' => 'root', 'uses' => 'SiteController@getRoot']);

Route::get('blog/{slug?}', ['as' => 'blog.post', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getPost']);
Route::get('blog/page/{page}', ['as' => 'blog.page', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getPage'])->where('page', '[0-9]+');
```

With this setup, it only uses the first route.

My question is. Is there a way to do this? Or, is this beyond capabilities of Laravel?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, place your first route as the last route.  That way it will get picked up last.  You may also need to place the `blog/{slug?}` before that one as well so `blog/slug/{page}` is first.

```
Route::get('blog/page/{page}', ['as' => 'blog.page', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getPage'])->where('page', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('blog/{slug?}', ['as' => 'blog.post', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getPost']);

Route::get('/{page?}', ['as' => 'root', 'uses' => 'SiteController@getRoot']);
```

Basically what happens is the most basic route is picking up the other routes because there is no reason for it not to and it technically matches the route even though it's not the route you want.  Putting the most specific routes first usually handles this issue.

Comment: Thank you. I kind of forgot that order can change that.

Answer (score 2):

Try reordering them:

```
Route::get('blog/page/{page}', ['as' => 'blog.page', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getPage'])->where('page', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('blog/{slug?}', ['as' => 'blog.post', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getPost']);

Route::get('/{page?}', ['as' => 'root', 'uses' => 'SiteController@getRoot']);
```

otherwise they get "overwritten"

Comment: To be fair @user3158900 answered 2 mins before me so he should get the accepted answer and he gave a better explanation